# How to use regsub in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I was replacing non alphanumerical character like `. \` etc using regsub command and it is not helping. Could you please help me

Text:

```
This is the new begin.\With old memories
```

Need to replace `".\"` to `.`
Expected:

```
This is the new begin.With old memories
```

Tries with

```
regsub -all {\.\\} $string {\.}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For literal strings, `string map` might be better.

Comment: What's the actual problem? What output is regsub actually giving you?

Comment: Keep in mind that the replacement string is not a pattern, it is a literal string. Instead of using `{\.}` just use `{.}` -- I suspect your "problem" is that you see the output `This is the new begin\.With old memories` with the backslash before the dot.

Answer (score 1):

As Donal said, just use [string map](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34) e.g.

```
% set a {This is the new begin.\With old memories}
This is the new begin.\With old memories
% string map {.\\ .} $a
This is the new begin.With old memories
```

As you can see, I had to escape the backslash with a second backslash.